# MaskedEditValidator DisplayMoney doesn't show up in Composite Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, composite-controls

I'm creating a simple composite control that has AJAX functionality. When trying to implement a MaskedEditValidator, the DisplayMoney property doesn't work. The MaskedEdit renders, without the dollar sign attached. Any ideas? Here's my code:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    priceTextbox.ID = this.ID + "_price";
    quantityTextbox.ID = this.ID + "_quantity";
    timeTextbox.ID = this.ID + "_time";
    submitButton.ID = this.ID + "_submit";
    submitButton.Text = "Submit";
    priceMask.TargetControlID = priceTextbox.ClientID.ToString();
    priceMask.ID = priceMask.TargetControlID.ToString() + "_extender";
    priceMask.BehaviorID = "priceMaskExtender";
    priceMask.Mask = "99.99";
    priceMask.DisplayMoney = MaskedEditShowSymbol.Left;

}
```

Comment: Your both right, but I have to give it to colithium because he posted first. I love how every comes out when a bounty is applied. Thanks all. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following line:

```
priceMask.MaskType = MaskedEditType.Number;
```

Optionally, set ClearMaskOnLostFocus to false if that is the behavior you want (it keeps the dollar sign even when not focused).

The DisplayMoney property setter only sets the property if MaskType is equal to MaskedEditType.Number.

```
set
{
   if (MaskType == MaskedEditType.Number)
   {
     SetPropertyValue("DisplayMoney", value);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The DisplayMoney property setter only sets the property if MaskType is equal to **MaskedEditType.Number**.

```
set
{
   if (MaskType == MaskedEditType.Number)
   {
     SetPropertyValue("DisplayMoney", value);
   }
}
```

So you need to set:

```
priceMask.MaskType = MaskedEditType.Number;
```